# Dynamic change of itemRorder value in RadListView UI in Nativescript Angular app

Tags: angular, nativescript, radlistview

I'm trying to dynamically change the value of itemReorder boolean in RadListView Ui list for Nativescript Angular App without success. I get every time this error: Behavior is not attached to RadListView, use RadListView addbehavior method to attach it.

HTML:

```
<GridLayout  tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton class="proposedLettersRow">
        <RadListView #itemReord [items]="items" selectionBehavior="LongPress" reorderMode = "Drag" [itemReorder]="itemReorder" (itemReordered)="onItemReordered($event)" multipleSelection= "false"
                    >
                <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                    <GridLayout class="listItemTemplateGrid" >
                        <Label
                            [text]="item"
                            [ngClass]="!isWin ?  'proposed' : 'proposedIsDone'"
                            class="list-group-item ">
                        </Label>
                    </GridLayout>
                </ng-template>

                <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout
                                    scrollDirection="Vertical"
                                    height="150"
                                    ios:itemHeight="150"
                                    spanCount="7"
                                    horizontalAlignment="center">
                </ListViewGridLayout>
        </RadListView>
    </GridLayout>
```

Typescript:

At the beginning this.itemReorder is set to  true, then a function comes to change it to false, the error appears when i execute this function.

[Terminal log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PObeI.jpg)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ1fY.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the code in text not via images in your question.

Comment: I have edited for add this

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue, let's know if you could update this [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=EjIK8s) with your code.

Comment: Playground updated, the code reproduce the issue: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=EjIK8s&v=2  @Manoj

Comment: drag an element up crash the App @Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are setting `itemReorder` to `false` too early, may be the component requires it to be `true` while on `itemReordered` event. Since it's not open source yet, I don't have much information on this. But an easy workaround is to add a timeout,

```
public youWin() {
    if (this.newIndex < this.oldIndex) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.itemReorder = false;
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=EjIK8s&v=3)